# Setting background color of a table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that stretches across the entire page.

I'm zebra striping using `nth-child` on the `tr`'s to set the `background` of the row. The problem is that it is only coloring the cells and not the entire row. You can see white space in between each cell of the colored rows.

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6q3r8bj9/.)

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: peachpuff;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do you change the `background` color of the entire row and not each individual cell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add [`border-collapse:collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) to `table`

> The border-collapse CSS property determines whether a table's borders
>   are separated or collapsed. In the separated model, adjacent cells
>   each have their own distinct borders. In the collapsed model, adjacent
>   table cells share borders.
>
> The separated model is the traditional HTML table border model.
>   Adjacent cells each have their own distinct borders. The distance
>   between them given by the border-spacing property.
>
> In the collapsed border model, adjacent table cells share borders. In
>   that model, the border-style value of inset behaves like groove, and
>   outset behaves like ridge.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: peachpuff;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS solution to this uses the `border-spacing` and `border-collapse` properties.

Here's your `table` rule, updated:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

It used to be that margin and padding in tables were primarily controlled in the HTML with the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes.

`<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10"> ... </table>`

But these attributes are now on a path to obsolescence. Use CSS.

Examples

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

To learn more about `border-collapse` see this article.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

Or via CSS

```
table {border-spacing: 0;}
```

Comment: `cellspacing` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

By default there is some spacing between the borders, to remove the spacing use

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

or

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

the `border-collapse: collapse` will merge the borders of cells in to one border while `border-spacing: 0` will decrease the space between the cells to show it as single border. I will prefer to use `border-collapse` because its purpose is to merge the borders into single border.